# CSS Fill ::before with background color

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to fill div::before with background color.
Its working when I set fixed width, but if I want:

```
width: auto;
```

Its not working.

If I set:

```
width: 100%;
```

It overlaps and fills same color to end of div.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Here is also jsfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/ofyt1cb8

If you set .container::before width to fixed length, its working. But I want it "snap" to centered div automatically.

Is this even possible?

Whole code:

```
<div class="container">
  CENTERED
</div>


.container {
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  height: 20px;
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you need a `::before` for this? Given your example, the same could be achieved with a border. http://jsfiddle.net/ofyt1cb8/38/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox can do that

```css
body {
  background: blue;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  color: #FFF;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.container:before,
.container:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  background: pink;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  CENTERED
</div>

<BR/>
<div class="container">
  CENTERED HEADING
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Using `calc()` and `vw`, you can set a fixed - but variable - width for the before:

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position:relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 100%;
  width: calc(50vw - 150px);
  height: 20px;
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

I have set the `.container` position to `relative`, to let the `:before` position itself from the div.

Setting `right: 100%;` on the `:before`, I make sure that the `:before` will start from the left side of the `.container` and move left.

Using calc(), we can make a math-equiation: 50vw equals half the Viewport Width (vw) and subtracting half of the .containers width (150px) will get the remaining width og the page.

Answer (score 0):

Width auto will not work since it has no contents.
You need to position your item a bit differently.

http://jsfiddle.net/ofyt1cb8/16/

```
.container {
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position:relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;;
  width: 50px;;
  height: 20px;
  background: #FF0000;
}
```

- Use `position: relative` on parent
- Position the child relative to the parent.
- Set a width, anything that is not `auto` or `0`

Answer (score 0):

use calc().

calc() is a CSS function that can be used anywhere a length, frequency, angle, time, number, or integer value is allowed. It lets you perform mathematical expressions with addition (+), subtraction (-), multiplication (*), and division (/), and then use the result of the expression as a value for a CSS property that accepts any of the previously-mentioned values.

```
width: calc((100% - 300px) / 2 );
```